# How to add a minimise button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have found many questions in stackoverflow regarding how to add a custom title bar in tkinter. It works for me, but none of the answers show how to add a minimise and maximise buttons on it. I am using a mac computer, so here is the code -

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x740")
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.overrideredirect(0)

Button(root, text="Close", command=root.quit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How can I add a minimise and maximise button in this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `root.wm_state('iconic')`

```
import tkinter as tk

class My_Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("300x300")

        tk.Button(
            self, text="Minimize",
            command=lambda: self.wm_state('iconic')
        ).pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = My_Window()
    app.mainloop()
```